Insert images into excel and then save them in a folder with the file name found in a cell
I need to gather 1,000s of images from a local folder. Is there a VBA that will insert them into the excel and then also save them as the file name listed in the excel column? I am able to insert the images from a local path and then save as an HTMl file to put the images in a folder, but they are named as pic001, pic002, etc.

This VBA script will read image filenames from Column A and insert each corresponding image into Column B of the same row. Make sure the images are stored in a specified local folder.
Sub InsertImages()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim imgFolder As String
Dim imgPath As String
Dim imgName As String
Dim cell As Range
Dim picture As Picture
Dim lastRow As Long

' Set the worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change to your sheet name

' Set the folder path where images are stored
imgFolder = "C:\path\to\your\images\" ' Change to your folder path

' Get the last row in the column where filenames are listed
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' Assuming filenames are in column A

' Loop through each cell in column A
For Each cell In ws.Range("A1:A" & lastRow)
    imgName = cell.Value
    imgPath = imgFolder & imgName
    
    ' Check if the file exists
    If Dir(imgPath) <> "" Then
        ' Insert the image
        Set picture = ws.Pictures.Insert(imgPath)
        
        ' Set the position of the image
        With picture
            .Top = cell.Offset(0, 1).Top ' Adjust column offset as needed
            .Left = cell.Offset(0, 1).Left
            .Placement = xlMoveAndSize
        End With
        
        ' Optionally, resize the image
        'picture.Width = 100
        'picture.Height = 100
    Else
        MsgBox "File not found: " & imgPath
    End If
Next cell

End Sub

That code worked to insert the images, but is there one that will save the images into a folder with the file name in column A?

Here it is, ensure your Excel sheet has a column with the image file names (without extension) that you want to use for renaming the images, and I assumed you put the name of the renamed names starting from A2 column, are you familiar with the basic process, or will the script be enough for you?
Sub InsertImagesAndRename()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim imgPath As String
Dim imgFolder As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim pic As Picture
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim imgDict As Object


Set imgDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")


Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change to your sheet name
imgFolder = "C:\path\to\your\images\" ' Change to your image folder path

' usual action
lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

' Loop through each cell in Column A
For i = 2 To lastRow
    fileName = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value
    
    ' file exisiting in the folder
    If Dir(imgFolder & fileName & ".jpg") <> "" Then
        ' Insert the image
        Set pic = ws.Pictures.Insert(imgFolder & fileName & ".jpg")
        
        'positioning
        pic.Top = ws.Cells(i, 2).Top
        pic.Left = ws.Cells(i, 2).Left
        
        
        imgDict.Add fileName, pic.Name
    End If
Next i


ThisWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp.html", FileFormat:=xlHtml


For Each fileName In imgDict
    Dim oldPath As String
    Dim newPath As String
    
    oldPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp_files\" & imgDict(fileName) & ".jpg"
    newPath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\temp_files\" & fileName & ".jpg"
    
    
    Name oldPath As newPath
Next fileName


MsgBox "Images have been inserted!", vbInformation

End Sub


Thank you! I am getting a Compile error: For each control variable must be variant or object. For Each fileName In imgDict
